# Can I run a LabVIEW webservice from Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi2, labview, webui

I noticed that there's a recent released apps that enables Raspberry Pi to run a deployed LabVIEW program all by itself and to set the program run as RPi boots. Since I was planning to remotely control the LabVIEW program through the internet using a Web UI, is it possible to setup a webservice of the program on the RPi? By the way, I'm currently planning to use RPi 2 for my project.

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting you right you are about LINX at Makers hub: https://www.labviewmakerhub.com/doku.php?id=blog:users:makerhub:2016-04-07-linx-3

It is open source, free tool. You are free to modify and it and add custom command on LINX Firmware as I understand. After that, you can call LabVIEW [Custom Command vi](https://www.labviewmakerhub.com/doku.php?id=learn:libraries:linx:reference:labview:custom-command) which is part of the API.

You can have a look on all API VIs here: https://www.labviewmakerhub.com/doku.php?id=learn:libraries:linx:reference:labview:start

Answer (score 1):

From the discussion thread [here](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/LINX-3-0-LabVIEW-for-BeagleBone-Black-and-Raspberry-Pi-2-3/td-p/3278758):

> We're running the LabVIEW Runtime on the target just like we do on our Linux based RIO devices.  The great thing about using the full runtime is that you get the standard LabVIEW expereince with interactive mode, highlight execute, probes, startup executables, etc.  This also means that all of the core LabVIEW functionality will work.  One way to think about it is anything that works without explicitly installing it on the target from MAX should work on BBB/RPI.  We actually don't plug into MAX at all. **We currently do not support any toolkits or modules, but we've been experimenting with a couple to see what it would take to support things like web services.**

So native LabVIEW web services aren't available yet, but may be coming soon - I'm sure development is responsive to what people ask for, so go to that discussion thread and let them know your interest.

You might be able to 'roll your own' simple web service using the TCP VI's, which as far as I can see should be available on the Raspberry Pi.

Note that deployment to Raspberry Pi or (BeagleBone Black) is only licensed for noncommercial use, as stated in the same thread.